# Get the size of a folder in Amazon S3 using Go SDK 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I know there are no folders in Amazon S3, but we can emulate them by using "/" on the key name.
Given that, is it possible using the [AWS SDK for Go v2](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2) to calculate the size of a folder? Or do I have to retrieve all objects in the folder and then calculate one by one the size?

Comment: List objects includes the size of each object. You can just sum the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given [that example](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/example/service/s3/listObjects/v0.2.9/example/service/s3/listObjects/listObjects.go), and the Object types documentation [here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3@v1.16.0/types#Object)

It is possible to compute the size occupied by items within a bucket

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
)

var (
    bucketName      string
    objectPrefix    string
    objectDelimiter string
    maxKeys         int
)

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&bucketName, "bucket", "", "The `name` of the S3 bucket to list objects from.")
    flag.StringVar(&objectPrefix, "prefix", "", "The optional `object prefix` of the S3 Object keys to list.")
    flag.StringVar(&objectDelimiter, "delimiter", "",
        "The optional `object key delimiter` used by S3 List objects to group object keys.")
    flag.IntVar(&maxKeys, "max-keys", 0,
        "The maximum number of `keys per page` to retrieve at once.")
}

// Lists all objects in a bucket using pagination
func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    if len(bucketName) == 0 {
        flag.PrintDefaults()
        log.Fatalf("invalid parameters, bucket name required")
    }

    // Load the SDK's configuration from environment and shared config, and
    // create the client with this.
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to load SDK configuration, %v", err)
    }

    client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    // Set the parameters based on the CLI flag inputs.
    params := &s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
        Bucket: &bucketName,
    }
    if len(objectPrefix) != 0 {
        params.Prefix = &objectPrefix
    }
    if len(objectDelimiter) != 0 {
        params.Delimiter = &objectDelimiter
    }

    // Create the Paginator for the ListObjectsV2 operation.
    p := s3.NewListObjectsV2Paginator(client, params, func(o *s3.ListObjectsV2PaginatorOptions) {
        if v := int32(maxKeys); v != 0 {
            o.Limit = v
        }
    })

    // Iterate through the S3 object pages, printing each object returned.
    var i int
    var total int64
    log.Println("Objects:")
    for p.HasMorePages() {
        i++

        // Next Page takes a new context for each page retrieval. This is where
        // you could add timeouts or deadlines.
        page, err := p.NextPage(context.TODO())
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to get page %v, %v", i, err)
        }

        // Log the objects found
        for _, obj := range page.Contents {
            // fmt.Println("Object:", *obj.Key)
            total += obj.Size
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("total", total)
}
```

Then, if I am correct, reading at [s3.ListObjectsV2Input](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3#ListObjectsV2Input) documentation, it appears to me that you can configure the `Prefix` member of the `s3.ListObjectV2Input` instance to select a specific folder. The example already demonstrates that if you pass in the flag `-prefix=...`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the easiest way, however you can iterate over your objects **list** of interest - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html, and aggregate the size locally.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

- enable AWS `storage lens` - `advanced metric` - `prefix aggregation` for your bucket, with exportation the metric as csv to a bucket
- get the csv data from the file in the bucket

note: the metric is exported every 24 hours